# Unable to search for user when passing name as parameter to function PHP SQL

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

I have the following function which works fine as the following:

```
function searchForRecordInUserTableUsername  ($connection){
    $sql ="SELECT ID FROM UserTable WHERE Username='WILL'";
    $stmt = sqlsrv_query($connection, $sql);
    if($stmt) {
        while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_NUMERIC) ) {
            echo $row[0];
        }
        sqlsrv_free_stmt( $stmt);
    }
    else {die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true)); }
}
```

However, I need to be able to pass the username is to the function as a parameter, as it depends on the user input. However, I don't seem to be able to get it to work. The following is what I have tried for the functions:

```
   function searchForRecordInUserTableUsername ($username, $connection){
    $sql ="SELECT ID FROM UserTable WHERE Username=(?)";
    $params = $username;
    $stmt = sqlsrv_query($connection, $sql, $params);
    if($stmt) {
        while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_NUMERIC) ) {
            echo $row[0];
        }
        sqlsrv_free_stmt( $stmt);
    }
    else {die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true)); }
}
```

And I have also tried:

```
function searchForRecordInUserTableUsername ($username, $connection){
$sql ="SELECT ID FROM UserTable WHERE Username=$username";
$stmt = sqlsrv_query($connection, $sql);
if($stmt) {
    while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_NUMERIC) ) {
        echo $row[0];
    }
    sqlsrv_free_stmt( $stmt);
}
else {die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true)); }
```

}

And when calling the function, I have put the username in singles quotes, double quotes and no quotes and it doesn't seem to be making a difference.

The following is an example of the error I am getting:

> Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 42S22 [SQLSTATE] => 42S22 [1] => 207 [code] => 207 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid column name 'WILL'. [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid column name 'WILL'. ) )

Does anyone know where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this function, change `$params` to be an array like this :

```
function searchForRecordInUserTableUsername ($username, $connection){
$sql ="SELECT ID FROM UserTable WHERE Username=(?)";
$params = array($username); //CHANGE HERE
$stmt = sqlsrv_query($connection, $sql, $params);
if($stmt) {
    while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_NUMERIC) ) {
        echo $row[0];
    }
      sqlsrv_free_stmt( $stmt);
  }
  else {die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true)); }
}
```